The need for functions, which traverse the rectangular grid.
Let $[N]$ denote the set $\{1,2, \ .. . \ ,N\}$ . For any $n,m \in \mathbb N$ what are some functions which traverse the grid $[n]\times[m]$, hitting each element exactly once? In particular, it would be nice to get a closed expression, for example, $(a,b)$ could be mapped to the binary number obtained by interleaving the bits of $a$ with $b$. But seems to only work when both $a$ and $b$ are powers of two. Please allow any extra assumptions if needed, and correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

So you want a bijection $[n]\times[m] \to [n\times m]$?

Would the identity map $f:[n]\times[m]\to[n]\times[m]$ suffice? If not, there's also $f(x,y)=(p_1x,p_2y)$ where $f:[n]\times[m]\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\text{gcd}(p_1,n)=\text{gcd}(p_2,m)=1$ composed by natural inclusion $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to[n]\times[m]$.

The obvious traversal order is $(a, b) \mapsto a + bn$ (using 0-indexing rather than 1-indexing).

@NaïmFavier, Thanks, both the answers work.

An obvious example would be the trivial function $f:[n]\times[m]\to[n]\times[m]$ where $f(a,b)=(a,b).$
More generally (in case you're looking for something a bit more complicated), another answer could be $g=i\circ f_{(p_1,p_2)}$ where $f(x,y)=(p_1x,p_2y),\ f:[n]\times[m]\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, $\text{gcd}(p_1,n)=\text{gcd}(p_2,m)=1$ and $i:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\to[n]\times[m]$ denotes natural inclusion.

Thanks, as mentioned in the other comment, I was looking for a bijection, (which is evident from writing a grid and enumerating) but I wanted a nice path traversal, which you gave.
